# After migrating a Q with an accepted A, I have 2×2 rep for accepting

Tags: support, reputation, migration, accepted-answer

Recently, my question [Show a 404 for not-found subdomains instead of showing root domain's content](https://serverfault.com/q/510325/152253) was migrated from Stack Overflow to Server Fault. That was after I accepted an answer.

Now, I got two rep for both SO as SF. Is this temporarily or by-design? Could you explain this behaviour?

<sup>[SO rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544337/camil-staps?tab=reputation); [SF rep](https://serverfault.com/users/152253/camil-staps?tab=reputation)</sup>

Comment: It's by design.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what's the idea? :)

Comment: It still answers the question.  I believe migration stubs are deleted from the original site after some period of time anyway, so the rep would be lost on the original site at that time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ah, I see. Could you make that an answer (if you have time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is by design because it still answers the question. If I am not mistaken, migration stubs are deleted from the original site after some period of time anyway, so the rep would be lost on the original site at that time.

Comment: Answer courtesy of Robert Harvey by way of the comment section.